# Why does `xrandr` say I have 3 HDMI and 3 DP ports while I have only one HDMI and one DP?

Tags: x11, xorg, xrandr, monitors

This is what `xrandr` shows on my machine:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1920x1080      50.0     60.0     30.0     25.0     24.0
   1920x1080i     50.0     60.1
   1600x1200      60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1152x864       75.0
   1280x720       50.0     60.0
   1024x768       75.1     60.0
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   720x576        50.0
   720x480        59.9
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9
   720x400        70.1
HDMI3 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1920x1080      50.0     60.0     30.0     25.0     24.0
   1920x1080i     50.0     60.1
   1600x1200      60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1152x864       75.0
   1280x720       50.0     60.0
   1440x576i      50.1
   1024x768       75.1     60.0
   1440x480i      60.1
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   720x576        50.0
   720x480        59.9
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9
   720x400        70.1
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have [ASUS Z97-A motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z97A/specifications/) which has `1 x DisplayPort` and `1 x HDMI` output but `Supports up to 3 displays simultaneously`. Is this why `xrandr` shows 3 `HDMI` and 3 `DP` ports (that would be strange)? If not, why does it? I have currently 2 monitor connected, one plugged intto `HDMI` and another one into `DP`.

EDIT: Or is this because of `daisy chain` that this motherboard supports? AFAIK, it doesn't work for HDMI but only for DisplayPort.